# Google API to retrieve all movies in a a category

Tags: youtube, gdata, movies

i am looking for a pi which can retrieve all movies available on youtube in a particular category.

for example i want list of movies available at http://www.youtube.com/movies?cl=te.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps YouTube API is what you are looking for:
http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/youtube/overview.html

Precisely, look into Data API Protocol. [There is parameter called "category"](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html#categorysp).

Comment: I have already gone through those api. but could not find api specific to fetch only movies. so is there anything in that documentation i am missing

Comment: I've extended my answer, check this [link](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html#categorysp).

Comment: Thanks adams for the answer. what i am looking at is api specific to just youtube movies.

like they provide api for movies as explained http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds.html#Movies_and_Trailers

but this will not return me the entire list of movies.